# What basic gems i need?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

hi im new to ruby on rails application development im just wondering what basic gems i need for my ruby on rails im a beginner and don't know what gems are important for a beginner like me

thanks please help

Comment: None. Don't deal with them until you need them. Depends on your app, too--you may never need any.

Comment: thanks for every one keep it coming :)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Dave (and certainly with Alex about railscasts!)

However it's good to know what's ahead and what's good to pick, so from experience I can recommend the following (when you are ready):

Initially:

- **rspec** for testing. Get into testing asap!
- **authlogic** for authentication. "Login"
- **simple_form** for views. (Saves hair extraction ;) )
- **mysql2** for your database or just use sqlite

As needed:

- **heroku** If you are deploying on heroku
- **resque** for background tasks.
- **activeadmin** for instant admin CRUD against tables.

Then (more experienced developer):

- **devise** for authentication. Does everything.
- **cancan** for user roles.  Great options for simple roles.
- **haml** for views.  Popular approach for cleaner code by removing `<`'s and `>`'s and 
  ruby `end`'s and html `</closing>` tags
- **pg** for Postgres
  You will also find this very helpful:  https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/

Comment: You mean authlogic, and haml is horrible ;)

Comment: Sorry Dave I mean Devise but then again maybe not for a beginner so authlogic is good there.  Most of the (good) rails programmers I know prefer haml however so we have opinions there :)

Comment: I use haml and erb interchangeably (in different projects). There are upsides to both. But worth knowing about both.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [`pry`](http://pry.github.com/) -- it's unbeatable for exploring your code and data. In Rails it's a pleasure to use as a `rails console` replacement.

I also recommend a gem of a book (see what I did there?) called [Rails AntiPatterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321604814) which will help you start writing clean Rails code. And The Rails Way, if you haven't already.

There are *so* many gems, that it's best to start looking only when you have an itch you assume someone else must have already scractched.

Answer (score 0):

Before using any gems I'd recommend you to go ahead and run this code in your Console.

```
rails g scaffold Foo bar:string faz:integer
```

This will generate a whole bunch of files in your project. 
Looking through the generated code helped me understand the fundamentals of a Rails application.

**But to answer your question:**
It really depends what functionality you want to add to your application.

I would also recommend to watch the [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/) video tutorials. Ryan features a lot of gems and also explains and compares them to similar ones.

Answer (score 0):

Generally I'd suggest picking up a good book
and working through it.

If Rails is what you're interested in, then check out;

- Ryan Bigg's ["Rails 3 in Action"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182277) (covers 3.1 in depth)
- Sam Ruby / Dave Thomas / DHH's ["Agile Web Development With Rails"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356549) (using rails 3.0)
- Obie Fernandez' ["The Rails Way"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321601661)

They will introduce you to the design patterns and workings required to build apps in Ruby and Rails.

And consequently, along the way, you'll find out how and when to use various different gems.

Asking what gems to use, without a context doesn't really get you anywhere, unfortunately.